# Recyclerview illegal state exception with data binding and viewModel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I am fetching a list of categories from an api and setting them into recyclerview . Adapter code is written in viewModel class and is called by the fragment that is calling the api. Below are the methods for setting adapters.

```
fun getAdapter(
   listener: OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapterListener,context: Context
): OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter {
    if (categoriesRecyclerAdapter == null)
        categoriesRecyclerAdapter = OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter(listener,context)

    return categoriesRecyclerAdapter as OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter

}

fun setItems(categories: ArrayList<OtherCategoriesItem>) {
    categoriesList = categories
    categoriesRecyclerAdapter!!.setItems(categoriesList!!)

}
```

And this is how I call these methods from my fragment class.

```
otherVideoViewModel.setItems(it.first.data!!.otherCategories as ArrayList<OtherCategoriesItem>)
```

Set Adapter method

```
private fun setAdapter() {
        otherVideosCategoriesBinding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        otherVideosCategoriesBinding.recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        adapter = otherVideoViewModel.getAdapter(adapterListener,activity!!)
        otherVideosCategoriesBinding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

And this is the adapter class.

```
class OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter(private val listener: OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapterListener,val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var categories = ArrayList<OtherCategoriesItem>()

    interface OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapterListener {
        fun onItemClicked(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val binding = ItemOtherVideoCategoryBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)

        return OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return categories.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = categories[position]
        holder.bindViews(item)

    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemOtherVideoCategoryBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bindViews(model: OtherCategoriesItem){
            binding.model=model
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

    }
    fun setItems(categoriesList: ArrayList<OtherCategoriesItem>) {
        categories = categoriesList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it crashes with following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewHolder views must not be attached when created. Ensure that you are not passing 'true' to the attachToRoot parameter of LayoutInflater.inflate(..., boolean attachToRoot)

I have tried all the related answers to this error but none of them worked for my case as many of those answers doesn't included data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just changing your onCreateViewHolder a bit. Try this:

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val binding:ItemOtherVideoCategoryBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.your_layout_name, parent, false)

    return OtherVideoCategoriesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder(binding)
}
```